# How to check empty list in Forms Ofbiz?

Tags: forms, ofbiz

I'm using service to generate a List Object and set to a field in Froms, but how to check this list empty or not ?. In this case, I want to check it in use-when attribute of another field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually invoke Java methods inside `use-when` directive that return a boolean true/false with something like:

```
use-when="mylist.isEmpty()"
```